# VB Script Integer division vs Float Division Rounding up

Tags: c#, asp.net, math

Hi Fellow stackoverflowers,

I'm having a problem converting a formula from `classic asp` `VBscript` to `C# .net`
I need `c#` to behave similar to the result of the `VBScript`

The formula goes like this

```
Dim dTravelHours, result
dTravelHours = 22.7359890666919
result = (CDbl(dTravelHours)*2 + 2)\8
```

Mathematically the result is  5.9331475 however since I used an integer division instead of Decimal division "/" The result is 5 , I can get this result properly in c# by simply type casting the result to int

however if I used a differently value:

```
Dim dTravelHours, result
    dTravelHours = 22.7359890666919
    result = (CDbl(dTravelHours)*2 + 2.5)\8
```

the mathematical result is 5.9956475
and vbScript result is 6

the same with 5.9456475 the `vbscript` result is 6

How do I replicate the same behavior in `C#` ?
I already tried using `Math.Floor,` `Math.Ceiling`, `Math.Round` but still no Good.

Thanks in advance for your answers and suggestions

Comment: Math.Ceiling(5.9956475) is 6, that is what you want right ?

Comment: Yes thats correct, but in VBScript 5.9331475 is 5 since it uses integer divison,but 5.9956475 is 6, if I simply use Ceiling in C# it will both have a result of 6 which is not the same result with the one in VBScript,

Comment: So 5.9331475 should be 5 and 5.9456475 should be 6? What's the rule for it?

Comment: Do you want 5 or 6 ? this should help you : http://salman-w.blogspot.co.id/2009/10/vbscript-ceil-and-floor-functions.html

Comment: Yes Tim, thats right, 5.9956475 is 6 as well,

Comment: Hi Stanley thanks for that reference, but its not the VBScript I need to fix, but the C# to behave similar to VBScript.

Comment: I notice that its like rounding up from the right most, 5.9456475, like this number it round up from the right most carrying over 1 to the next one. until it gets 6, however  5.9331475 this number does not carry over having a result of simply 5.9 and will be truncated to 5 if stored in integer. I wonder how do I do that in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MSDN states the VbScript [integer division operato](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzydt0tx(v=vs.84).aspx)r is implemented in this way:

> The result is the integer quotient of number1 divided by number2. The
>   integer quotient discards any remainder and retains only the integer
>   portion. Before division is performed, numeric expressions are rounded
>   to Byte, Integer, or Long subtype expressions.

[`Round`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se6f2zfx(v=vs.84).aspx) is implemented in this way: it returns integers by default and rounds  half to even or banker's rounding (default in C#).

So you can use this C# version using `Math.Round` and integer division:

```
double value = 22.7359890666919;
double calculationResult1 = value * 2 + 2.0;
double calculationResult2 = value * 2 + 2.5;
double rounded1 = Math.Round(calculationResult1);  // 47
double rounded2 = Math.Round(calculationResult2 ); // 48
int result1 = (int)rounded1 / 8;  // 5
int result2 = (int)rounded2 / 8;  // 6
```

Comment: Wow Tim! never thought of that, I just separated the formula in Math.Round before dividing by 8 and it worked! Thanks!